# Add only 1 tag on click to inputfield (multiple tags available) - jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, click

i'm using this jquery code:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#text_tag_input').val($('#text_tag_input').val()+$(this).html()+', ');
});
```

to add tags into the inputfield by clicking the links:

```
<input id="text_tag_input" type="text" name="tags" />

<div class="tags_select">
    <a href="#">tag1</a>
    <a href="#">tag2</a>
    <a href="#">tag3</a>
</div>
```

SEE DEMO ON [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dRQwC/)

But now i want to add only 1 tag.

Example:
when i click on tag1 it has to display in the inputfield.
when i now click for example on tag2 the inputfield should clear tag1 and insert tag2 to the inputfield.
so i can choose only 1 tag from 3 (or more)

is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?. You just need to change your code a bit. That's it.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#text_tag_input').val($(this).html()); // or $('#text_tag_input').val(this.innerHTML);
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hu7qS/)**

Answer (score 1):

It's actually much simpler to do that than what you are doing now:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#text_tag_input').val($(this).html());
});
```

This will replace the value in the box instead of adding to it.